# css active state for many elements

Tags: html, css

I have a div and inside this div there is an icon with background and text.

when clicking on this div I want to change 3 things:
the div background, the icon background and the text color.
how can I do it with CSS only?

http://jsfiddle.net/g1nrye8e/

```
<div class="click">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">text</div> 
</div>

.click{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
.icon{
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
.text{
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g1nrye8e/1/)?

Comment: Adding a good reference link talking about various options. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/

Answer (score 2):

## Preserve clicked state using pure CSS

The best way to **preserve the clicked state**, **without**  JavaScript is to

- wrap your elements inside a `<label>`
- immediately before the element you want to target place an invisible `input checkbox`
- when the input becomes `:checked` target any first **next sibling** element using `+*` and change styles accordingly
- Repeat the same rule for `+*`'s inner elements:

```css
/* DEFAULT STYLES */
.div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin:10px;
}
.icon{
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text{
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* HIDE CHECKBOX HELPER */
label.click > input{ /* hide the input checkbox */
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
}

/* ACTIVE STYLES */
label.click > input:checked +* { /* (the next .div) */
  background: #000;
}
label.click > input:checked +* .icon{
  background: #c0ffee;
}
label.click > input:checked +* .text{
  color: #f00ba4;
}
```

```html
    <label class="click">
      <input type="checkbox"> <!-- :checked state changes +div styles -->
      <div class="div">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="text">text</div> 
      </div>
    </label>
    
    <label class="click">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div class="div">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="text">text</div> 
      </div>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the parent when it is clicked, then write more specific CS for that class.

Here's a running example.

```js
document.querySelector(".click").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("clicked"); 
});
```

```css
.click{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
.icon{
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text{
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
.clicked.click{
  background: green;
}
.clicked .icon{
  background: red;
}
.clicked .text{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="click">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="text">text</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different solution with only css, but you have to click to every element:

```css
.click{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
.icon{
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
.text{
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
.click:focus{
    background: red;
}
.icon:focus{
    background: grey;
}
.text:focus{
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="click" tabindex="1">
    <div class="icon" tabindex="2"></div>
    <div class="text" tabindex="3">text</div> 
</div>
```

There is a great explanations about the `tabindex` and `:focus` without using JS. Check it out [impressivewebs](http://www.impressivewebs.com/using-tabindex-with-focus/)